# JSON loads fails on invaild escape characters

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am getting a large data file from external service, where each line is a json object. However, it contains multiple hex characters like (\xef,\xa0,\xa9) etc and some unicode characters like (\u2022) .I am basically reading the file like

```
with open(filename,'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        attr = json.loads(line)
```

I tried giving encoding utf-8 and latin-1 to the open method, but still json loads is failing. If the invalid characters are removed then loads is working, but I don't want to lose any data. What's the recommended way to fix this ?

repr(line) sample:

```
'{"product_type":"SHOES","recommended_browse_nodes":"361208011","item_name":["Citygate  960561 Ankle Boots Womens  Gray Grau (anthrazit 9) Size: 8 (42 EU)"],"product_description":[],"brand_name":"Citygate","manufacturer":"J H P\\xf6lking GmbH & Co KG","bullet_point":[],"department_name":"Women\\u2019s","size_name":"42 EU","material_composition":["Leather"]}\n'
```

json.loads is failing at \xf6 in item_name with Invalid \escape: line 1 column 105 (char 104) .

Comment: either your file is valid JSON or it isn't. Can you provide us with a proper sample? `\u2022` is valid JSON syntax. If you have *literal text* with `\xef` then that's not valid JSON. If those are bytes, show use the `repr()` output of such a line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added sample and error.

Comment: That's not one line, nor is it the output of `repr()`. We can't determine if `\xa0` is a single byte or 4 separate characters this way.

Comment: Although the error message does imply that you have literal text here and not a single byte, making this *invalid* JSON.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added repr() for the line . It's one line only, I had formatted for readability. As I mentioned, I don't have control over the file contents. Can you suggest a  way to convert literals like \xa0 into the corresponding character ?

Comment: Out of time right now; may come back later. You have invalid JSON and a regex can fix these; I did write answers before covering cases like these.

Comment: I found a previous answer of mine where I include a regex that fixes this problem: `import re`, `escape_sequence = re.compile(r'\\x([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})')`, `def repair(string): return escape_sequence.sub(r'\\u00\1', string)`; just use `json.loads(repair(line))` rather than `json.loads(line)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the JSON string with regex as @Martijn mentioned. Here is a verbose example.

```
import re
import json

s = '{"product_type":"SHOES","recommended_browse_nodes":"361208011","item_name":["Citygate  960561 Ankle Boots Womens  Gray Grau (anthrazit 9) Size: 8 (42 EU)"],"product_description":[],"brand_name":"Citygate","manufacturer":"J H P\\xf6lking GmbH & Co KG","bullet_point":[],"department_name":"Women\\u2019s","size_name":"42 EU","material_composition":["Leather"]}\n'

xinvalid = re.compile(r'\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})')

def fix_xinvalid(m):
    return chr(int(m.group(1), 16))

def fix(s):
    return xinvalid.sub(fix_xinvalid, s)

print(json.loads(fix(s)))
```

and the output:

```
{'recommended_browse_nodes': '361208011', 'bullet_point': [], 'product_description': [], 'brand_name': 'Citygate', 'size_name': '42 EU', 'material_composition': ['Leather'], 'product_type': 'SHOES', 'item_name': ['Citygate  960561 Ankle Boots Womens  Gray Grau (anthrazit 9) Size: 8 (42 EU)'], 'department_name': 'Women’s', 'manufacturer': 'J H Pölking GmbH & Co KG'}
```

Comment: The `\uhhhh` escapes are perfectly valid. Only the `\xhh` escapes need fixing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, wasn't aware. Removing them...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it does indeed give the same result